# Android- Next Class function

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, xamarin

Please i will like to have a method/function in a separate class 
that will enable me to go to next activity or fragment class when i call it
here is my little try of code

inside my go_to.class i have this below

for activity

```
void goToActivity(Activity t){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, t.class));
    }

void goToFragment(Fragment f,package.com.R l){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(l,new f).commit();
    }
```

and to use example

```
goToActivity(mynextactivity.class);

goToFragment(mynextfragment.class,R.id.fragment_layout);
```

Any help is welcome

Comment: And your problem is???

Comment: my problem was i am getting error

Comment: why did you down vote my question i am only looking for help

Comment: this is really not **fear

Comment: How we can help if we dont know whats your error ? :)

Comment: if you like to help you post example not down voting question

Comment: What error are you getting? Post the text of the error, or a screenshot or something. We are not mind-readers.

Comment: here is the line i am getting from first method `startActivity(new Intent(this, t.class));// unknown class`

Comment: then second method/function is like this, since resources id cannot be determine so i want have a piece of code that i can override latter in activity/fragment class to go to the fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later solve it this way after many trial:
What i am trying to achive is to have a function to call new activity class and fragment when a button is clicked on at runtime

```
void goToActivity(Class t){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, t));
    }
```

my where i have been getting the fragment concept wrong is fragment is not indepent activity class, so to overcome fragment need anactivity parent or root layout to hold the fragment layout that is you can never start fragment instance alone like activity which is very big issure for begginers to understand

```
void goToFragment(Fragment f){
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.your_layout, f);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
```

or if you cannot determine your xml layout you can write it like this:

```
void goToFragment(int l,Fragment f){
            fragmentTransaction.replace(l, f);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
```

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

From non activity class you can create a function it like this:

```
public static void goToHomeActivity(Context context)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(context, ActivityDashboard.class);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

Then call it like this `MyUtils.goToHomeActivity(context);`

Alternatively, from activity class like this:

```
private void goToHomeActivity()
{
    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ActivityDashboard.class);
    context.startActivity(i);
}`
```

Then call it like this `goToHomeActivity();`